# Vanilla Forum Nginx X_Rewrite doesn't work

Tags: nginx, vanilla-forums

I built a own forum site using vanilla forum

I setup nginx config file with this page https://docs.vanillaforums.com/developer/backend/server-nginx/

with using **fastcgi_param X_REWRITE 1;**
i can't move from top page
no links are working

without using **fastcgi_param X_REWRITE 1;**
links are working
but url has a parameter, like
http://example.com/**index.php?p=**/category/

i wanna remove **index.php?p=** from url and i wanna know why **fastcgi_param X_REWRITE 1;** doesn't wotk

please help me